# Is it fair to charge client for FontAwesome pro license as development charges?

Tags: freelance-websites, invoices, billing

I have to develop a simple presentation website. I own a Pro License of FontAwesome which I used in the application.

I didn't subscribed to the license for the website specifically, but is it fair to include any fee in the invoice as long as I used it in the project ?

I'm actually wondering if it is ethically fair to do so

Comment: It's almost a certainty that FontAwesome includes information in their license agreement as to what you can and cannot do with their product. Have you read the license agreement?

Answer (score 5):

If I have a client which needs to run something requiring a license, they purchase a license (through me) so they can continue to use the licensed product.

If I purchase a license, it's so I [my company] can legally use the product. So I would be free to show mockups or other things using the product. Then if a client chooses a mockup containing a licensed product, the client pays for a license so *they* can use the product.

It's not only ethical, it's how it *should* be done. If you fail to purchase a license for your client, then you need to relinquish *your* license to the product. If you have only one license, in most instances, only **one** company/individual can use the product.